What is the intended use of the technical-analysis tag?
I always assumed that the technical-analysis tag referred to technical chart analysis, i.e. the prediction of future BTC exchange rates based on chart patterns and the psychology of trading. However, it seems to be used as a substitute for the technical tag, i.e. analyzing the technical behavior of the Bitcoin protocol or Bitcoin client.
There is no wiki tag, so I am not sure if my interpretation is correct. Before I added any wiki text or did any retagging, I wanted to ask meta for the consensus opinion on its meaning.

Barring some dissent or discussion here, I may add a definition for the tag and do some retagging later in the week.

I've looked over the questions tagged with the tag and most of them are better served with the "architecture" tag instead, so if we achieve a consensus here it should be fine to keep that tag for chart analysis.

I agree that technical-analysis should specifically refer to technical chart analysis.  Upvote here if you do too.
